# On projective dimension of quotients of polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, $B=A[X]/(X^2)$, and $C=B/(x)$. (Here $x$ denotes the residue class of $X$ modulo $(X^2)$.) Why the projective dimension of $C$ is infinite ?

Comment: Do you mean projective dimension as a $B$ or as an $A$-module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you ment projective dimension as a $B$-module.

Have you tried finding a projective resolution? It's not that hard. Here's how: First off, you have an obvious surjection $B \to C \to 0$ sending the class of $X$ to zero. What is the kernel? Well, it's the ideal generated by $X$. So we have a minimal projective resolution of the form
$$
\cdots \to B \xrightarrow{\cdot x} B \xrightarrow {\cdot x} B \xrightarrow{x \mapsto 0} C \to 0$$

<strike>It is minimal because each map lands in the maximal ideal.</strike>

You must prove that it is minimal, however.

Comment: Thank you, Fredik meyer !! I want to know the definition of "minimal"projective resolution

Comment: By definition, minimal means that the image of each boundary map $\partial(B)$ lies in the maximal ideal, that is, $\partial(B) \subseteq \mathfrak{m}B$.

Comment: I see. Sorry,I have one more question. If length of minimal projective resolution is infty, projectibe dimension is infty?why??

Comment: As far as I know the notion of minimal resolution involves a local ring. Which one is *the* maximal ideal in this case? Maybe you want to localize first.

Comment: @YACP: I guess you're right. Do you know if it is minimal in each localization, then it is in some sense minimal over $B$?

Comment: I don't know what minimal could mean in general, but in this case if localize at a prime containing $x$ you get that the projective dimension of the localization is infinite and this should be enough.